# I get this error when trying flutter upgrade

Tags: flutter

I get this error when I tried `flutter upgrade`

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At C:\Users\USER\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:4
+ (& "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "ho ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\USER\a...ripts\conda.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Currently, I don't have anaconda installed in my system

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda is a distribution of the Python and it has nothing to do with flutter in any way.
Make sure that you write the right command in the terminal.

Comment: I'm sorry, right command means what?
I just opened cmd in the folder in which flutter is installed and tried flutter upgrade and I got this error. Is there anything else I should do? Flutter was working fine before I tried this.
I'm new to flutter, so I don't know much.

Comment: That's weird, double check to your env path, read this doc for instructions https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows